# Why are updates pushed to Fedora's updates-testing repos initially invisible?

Tags: fedora, yum

I follow various bugs on [Red Hat Bugzilla](http://bugzilla.redhat.com/), and I just received a notification from the Fedora Update System that a new package was available for testing that supposedly fixes a bug I was interested in. I wanted to test it, so I tried to follow the instructions.

Unfortunately, although the packages are described as having been "pushed to updates-testing", I see no evidence that they are actually there yet. It seems somewhat silly to publish a command for testing an update that initially *doesn't work*, but this is apparently what they are doing on a regular basis!

I tried a couple of things:

1. Commented out `mirrorlist` and uncommented `base-url` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates-testing.repo` to make it use (what I *believe* to be) the "master" public download site
2. `yum clean all`

but these made no difference to the outcome - still no new packages available, according to yum.

Details: It's mesa-libGL (and the other mesa packages) for Fedora 14.

Comment: Sanity check: did you run `yum update`?

Comment: @Gilles: Yes - that's the command I was told to use (with some arguments). Remember, yum update is not the same as apt-get update - yum does what apt-get update does automatically. It works now, but it didn't last night.

Comment: The Fedora Update System now posts messages which clearly state that there may be a delay of up to two days. I'm pleased that the messages are now more accurate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you can use:

```
yum clean expire-cache
yum repolist -v updates-testing
```

...which will show you both the last time that Fedora updated (in the metalink/updated row) and the last time you updated (in the repo-updated row). As a quick check you can also just run "yum repolist" on it's own, and any rows that start with a '*' do not have the latest metadata locally.

AIUI Fedora post the messages about packages being pushed as they are approved ... but it can still be a non-trivial amount of time after that before they are in the Fedora repo. (and longer for your local mirror to sync.)